# Question regarding the algebra of norms

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonality

I am new to linear algebra, as am having some doubts regarding the following question:

True or False

$u,v \in R^n$

1. $\left\lVert u\right\rVert=\left\lVert v\right\rVert$ if and only if u+v and u-v are orthogonal.
2. For every $u,v \in R^n$ and every $c \in R$: $\left\lVert cu+v\right\rVert^2=c^2\left\lVert u\right\rVert^2+2c(u·v)+\left\lVert v\right\rVert^2$

I worked out with basic algebra that 1 is true. However I am doubting re 2: algebraically it makes sense, and I have put in two sets of numbers that both came out correct, but I am doubting whether there might be a detail that I am missing (because the question states "for *every* u,v…"

Thank you!

Comment: To state your proof of 2. rigorously: First, write out the single algebraic sentence that "shows" that the LHS of the Equation is equal to the RHS. Second, put brackets around that sentence and precede it with $\forall u,v\in \Bbb R^n\,\forall c\in \Bbb R.$ That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

Just using the definition of the norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$: for $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ $||u||:=\sqrt{(u,u)}$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ represents the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
Now $||cu+v||^2={\sqrt{(cu+v,cu+v)}}^2=(cu+v,cu+v)=(cu+v,cu)+(cu+v,v)=(cu,cu)+(v,cu)+(cu,v)+(v,v)=||cu||^2+(cu,v)+(cu,v)+||v||^2=c^2||u||^2+2c(u,v)+||v||^2$ 
using the bilinearity and scalar multiplication of the inner product.